# FastAPI: Uvicorn Logging which Sub Application was called

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, uvicorn

While refactoring our FastAPI we want to keep the initial version running and temporarily mount a duplicated API like

```
api = FastAPI()
api_v2 = FastAPI()
api.mount("/v2", api_v2)
uvicorn.run(
    api(),
    host="0.0.0.0",
    port=5010,
    log_config=uvicorn_logger_config,
)
```

Unfortunately, we can't see from the logs, whether `/status` or `/v2/status` was called:

```
2022-07-20 16:45:43,878 [INFO] ←[1mGET /status HTTP/1.1←[0m from 127.0.0.1:61305 - ←[32m200 OK←[0m
2022-07-20 16:45:49,101 [INFO] ←[1mGET /status HTTP/1.1←[0m from 127.0.0.1:61307 - ←[32m200 OK←[0m
```

Is there a simple way to mark with `logging` which sub application was called?

Comment: More information needed. Do you not see logs of the type `INFO: 127.0.0.1:NNNNN - "GET /app/?XXX HTTP/1.1" 304 Not Modified` where you can see if the URL is relative to `/v2`?

Comment: Exactly, I tried to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an [open uvicorn issue about this](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/1384). You should probably monitor it for updates.